# Any way to automatically correct all variable classes in a dataframe

Tags: sql, r, database, sqldf

I have a dataframe with about ~250 variables. Unfortunately, all of these variables were imported as character classes from a sql database using `sqldf`. 
The problem: all of them should not be character classes. There are numeric variables, integers, as well as dates. I'd like to build a model that runs over all the variables and to do this I need to make sure that variables have the right classes. Doing it one by one is probably best, but still very manual.

How could I automatically correct all classes? Perhaps a way to detect whether there are alphabet characters in the column or only number characters?

I don't think it's possible for an automatic approach to be perfect in correcting all classes. But it might correct most of the classes, then those that are not good, I can take care of them manually.

I am adding a sqldf tag in case anybody knows of any way to correct this when importing the data, but I assume it's not sqldf's fault but rather the database's.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The closest thing to "automatic" type conversion on a data frame would probably be

```
df[] <- lapply(df, type.convert)
```

where `df` is your data set. The function `type.convert()`

> Converts a character vector to logical, integer, numeric, complex or factor as appropriate.

Have a read of `help(type.convert)`, it might be just what you want.

In my experience, `type.convert()` is very reliable. You can use `as.is = TRUE` if you don't want characters coerced to factors. Plus it's used internally in many important R functions (like `read.table`), so it's definitely safe.

Here's a quick example of it working on `iris`.  First we'll change all columns to character, then run `type.convert()` on it.

```
## Original column classes in iris
sapply(iris, class)
# Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
#    "numeric"    "numeric"    "numeric"    "numeric"     "factor" 

## Change all columns to character
iris[] <- lapply(iris, as.character)
sapply(iris, class)
# Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
#  "character"  "character"  "character"  "character"  "character" 

## Run type.convert()
iris[] <- lapply(iris, type.convert)
sapply(iris, class)
# Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
#    "numeric"    "numeric"    "numeric"    "numeric"     "factor"
```

We can see that the columns were returned to their original classes.  This is because `type.convert()` coerces columns to the "most appropriate" type.

Comment: hello Richard, I recently used this on a different data frame and it gave this error `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : the first argument must be of mode character` I was wondering if you knew why this was happening

Comment: it looks like type.convert() expects a character vector as its first argument. I have tried converting my df to as.character(df) but then it just converted everything into factor type

Comment: @jgozal If you want characters to remain characters and not be coerced to factors, set `as.is=TRUE` in `type.convert`

Comment: won't that still convert the other columns to characters though?

Comment: @jgozal - It will coerce them to their appropriate type.  So if R decides they should be numeric, they will be numeric.  Try it out. `type.convert(as.character(1:5))` goes back to numeric, `type.convert(letters[1:5])` goes to factor, and `type.convert(letters[1:5], as.is = TRUE)` remains character

Comment: so if I understand correctly. If I want to solve this issue and still convert my df to what R thinks each column should be converted to, I should do `df[] <- lapply(as.character(df), type.convert)`? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @jgozal - No, you would have to do `df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x), as.is = TRUE))`  That way you will have no factor columns.  If you want R to decide about factors, leave out `as.is = TRUE`.  You cannot run `as.character()` on a data frame, only on atomic vectors one-by-one

Comment: I see. So just to clarify the process there. Would the function above be converting each vector in the dataframe to a character vector? then type.convert() converts each vector to the appropriate class/type. And I would only leave `as.is =TRUE` if I didn't want type.convert() to convert any character vectors to factors. Is this correct?